# Failed create chat room in android and getting No response from server (tigase server)

Tags: android, tigase

I'm developing an IM app use tigase as server, and use asmack library in android side. Now I can do register/login/chat p2p, but when I create chat room, I met a problem, android side code as below:

```
XMPPConnection connection = XmppConnectionManager.getInstance().getConnection();
try {
    MultiUserChat muc = new MultiUserChat(connection, "testroom" + "@" +  
        connection.getServiceName());
muc.create("nickname");
    ------
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

After execute muc.create("nickname"), It's always throw exception, and exception info is: No response from server. In tigase server side, I'm enabled the MUC component in etc/init.properties as below:

```
--comp-name-1 = muc
--comp-class-1 = tigase.muc.MUCComponent
```

I have modify the project as the question 
[create a group chat functionality in android and getting No response from server.. on muc.create()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390579/create-a-group-chat-functionality-in-android-and-getting-no-response-from-server)
But still do not work,I do not know why, need your kindly help.

Comment: I think your MUC component isn't working. First please verify whether your MUC component is working or not using Pidgin or PSI client.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. MUC component is working correctly. I can found "Multi user chat" in "Service Discovery" through PSI.

Comment: if you cannot find MUC in service discovery then MUC isn't working

Comment: I can find MUC in service discovery.

Comment: @Haider, I have used asmack library in Android side, I do not if problem exist when the communication between asmack and tigase server. And do you have experience on development android IM app, and server side is tigase.

Comment: I have experience of Tigase server customization, i think you should check you code from client side wheather or not its correctly sending request to server

Comment: same thing happed to me one year ago when was 100% sure that MUC is running but i wasn't running on Tigase side. As you said it is running then i must say GOOGLE it How to create MUC room on XMPP using Asmak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this problem. It's my fault in client side, I must specify the MUC service name as configured in server side, It's different with tigase service name, configured as below:

```
--virt-hosts = localhost  #tigase server name
--external= muc.localhost:muc-pass  #muc.localhost is muc service name
```

So the client side code is as below:

```
   MultiUserChat muc = new MultiUserChat(connection, roomName  
                + "@muc." + connection.getServiceName());
```

Thanks to @Haider.

Comment: oooopppsss sorry i forget to tell you at fist that how to address a component in TIGASE. Good to see you figured it out